# List all questions with close votes

Tags: support

Is there a quick way to see all the questions that have close votes on them?

I see a few questions closed that I probably would have voted against closing, and a whole bunch where I wholeheartedly agree they should be closed.

I have the review  link, but it only shows the questions/answers that have been flagged up automatically.  This seems entirely based on things like question length, how long the person has been in the community etc.  But a short question can be a good question, and people who have been here for years post the odd question or answer that is truly awful.

Is there anywhere that content that has been deemed low quality or unwelcome by actual people is shown.

Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: Strange, I've never noticed an option to oppose votes. Where is it?

Comment: @JohnGardeniers There isn't. If you see a question that has close votes and you want it to remain open, all you can do is watch it and vote to reopen if it gets closed. And, of course, make people less inclined to vote to close it by editing it for improvements or adding a comment explaining why it's a good question.

Comment: That is a very good point.  I think that people forget about that option.  There should be more editing for quality...  So my question is a bit invalid.  If people with low reputation had access to a Votes to Close list it would probably just mean certain kinds of people hung out there closing questions for the hell of it.  I don't think that would be good for the community.

Answer (score 4):

We have a  [**vote to close chat room**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/161/server-fault-vote-to-close) is used for highlighting questions to close. It generally works quite well.

Whilst it only takes 3k to be able to vote it unfortunately takes 10k to get to the tools to help you do this. I believe that this is because it is relatively easy to get 3k on StackOverflow so people 'come into their powers' before they may have absorbed enough of the culture to use them correctly. Sadly this isn't true of SF and other stackexchange sites where gaining 3k rep is quite an achievement and most people will have absorbed the culture by the time they get there.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you have above 10,000 reputation. Then you get a new menu item called "tools", where you can review all the questions with close votes.

Comment: It doesn't really count as "quick"... it'll take a few days for dunxd to go from 3k to 10k.  <grin>

Comment: Ah well - I'll wait.  I suppose I should be doing my job anyway :-)  Or answering some questions...